# I am trying to convert my jar file into a heroku based url but the App keeps crashing with an H10-App crashed error

Tags: java, web, url, heroku

Here is my Pom.xml file code that I'm sure is missing some sort of web based configuration that will likely prevent it running correctly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>newpackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>mcmDashboard</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>newpackage.Mission2Market</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>    
    <name>M2M App</name>
    <description>This is application was created by Jared Longmire in order to 
assist Florida International University: Applied Research Center
in creating a useful product for entrepreneurship under
Mission-to-Market director J. Chris Ford

</description>
</project>
```

Here is my Procfile that could also be missing information as well as I am not to familiar with what a Procfile needs to successfully run through Heroku

```
web: java -jar target/mcmDashboard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Here is the error message I'm receiving from the Heroku Logs which is H10 error https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running

```
2021-03-25T18:46:34.850737+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=m2mlifter.herokuapp.com request_id=cca64ade-1372-4263-a71e-50652bea1884 fwd="99.120.129.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is my full log trace using the heroku command heroku logs --tail

```
2021-03-25T17:57:09.691814+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
2021-03-25T17:57:09.691869+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
2021-03-25T17:57:09.691920+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
2021-03-25T17:57:09.691970+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2021-03-25T17:57:10.800584+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-03-25T17:57:10.930582+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-25T18:45:52.179393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=m2mlifter.herokuapp.com request_id=4913a381-b363-4216-b52c-0827b849d33c fwd="99.120.129.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-25T18:46:34.850737+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=m2mlifter.herokuapp.com request_id=cca64ade-1372-4263-a71e-50652bea1884 fwd="99.120.129.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-25T18:50:09.509750+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=m2mlifter.herokuapp.com request_id=db7ef0b8-0053-4c87-9a8a-aad08efe481a fwd="3.80.167.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-03-25T23:46:16.527086+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-25T23:46:20.927312+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar target/mcmDashboard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
2021-03-25T23:46:23.268465+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-03-25T23:46:23.272739+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2021-03-25T23:46:24.436624+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException:
2021-03-25T23:46:24.436656+00:00 app[web.1]: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
2021-03-25T23:46:24.436657+00:00 app[web.1]: but this program performed an operation which requires it.
2021-03-25T23:46:24.437612+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:165)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.437674+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:545)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.437750+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.437889+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:388)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.437938+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438017+00:00 app[web.1]: at newpackage.NewJFrame3.<init>(NewJFrame3.java:34)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438039+00:00 app[web.1]: at newpackage.Mission2Market.JFrame(Mission2Market.java:129)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438114+00:00 app[web.1]: at newpackage.Mission2Market$3.run(Mission2Market.java:174)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438172+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438227+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438283+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438349+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438418+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438498+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438570+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438645+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438693+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438779+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438835+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438910+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
2021-03-25T23:46:24.438958+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2021-03-25T23:46:25.515565+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-03-25T23:46:25.589023+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-26T05:21:06.510966+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-26T05:21:11.975504+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar target/mcmDashboard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
2021-03-26T05:21:15.131405+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-03-26T05:21:15.147778+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2021-03-26T05:21:17.454545+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException:
2021-03-26T05:21:17.454572+00:00 app[web.1]: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
2021-03-26T05:21:17.454574+00:00 app[web.1]: but this program performed an operation which requires it.
2021-03-26T05:21:17.455457+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:165)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.455515+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:545)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.455574+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.455653+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:388)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.455709+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.455765+00:00 app[web.1]: at newpackage.NewJFrame3.<init>(NewJFrame3.java:34)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.455839+00:00 app[web.1]: at newpackage.Mission2Market.JFrame(Mission2Market.java:129)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.455884+00:00 app[web.1]: at newpackage.Mission2Market$3.run(Mission2Market.java:174)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.455954+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.456029+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.456088+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.456147+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.456217+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.456299+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.456366+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.456439+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.456509+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.456584+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.456660+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.456732+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
2021-03-26T05:21:17.456801+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2021-03-26T05:21:21.507441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-03-26T05:21:21.619388+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-26T11:06:01.292450+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-26T11:06:04.995592+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar target/mcmDashboard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
2021-03-26T11:06:07.357646+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-03-26T11:06:07.362429+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2021-03-26T11:06:08.318718+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException:
2021-03-26T11:06:08.318737+00:00 app[web.1]: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
2021-03-26T11:06:08.318739+00:00 app[web.1]: but this program performed an operation which requires it.
2021-03-26T11:06:08.319417+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:165)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.319467+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:545)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.319546+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.319620+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:388)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.319689+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.319762+00:00 app[web.1]: at newpackage.NewJFrame3.<init>(NewJFrame3.java:34)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.319829+00:00 app[web.1]: at newpackage.Mission2Market.JFrame(Mission2Market.java:129)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.319897+00:00 app[web.1]: at newpackage.Mission2Market$3.run(Mission2Market.java:174)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.319971+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.320041+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.320107+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.320195+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.320269+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.320340+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.320408+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.320486+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.320553+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.320628+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.320714+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.320785+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
2021-03-26T11:06:08.320851+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2021-03-26T11:06:09.376663+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-03-26T11:06:09.448967+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-26T14:21:10.211908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=m2mlifter.herokuapp.com request_id=a6d76618-d910-44f3-a920-05b909ab9770 fwd="99.120.129.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is my systems.properties file as well

```
#Mon Mar 22 22:48:25 CDT 2021
java.runtime.version=15
maven.version=3.6.2
username=Jared L
```

Comment: Add the full log trace, also do you have a system.properties file?

Comment: @BeppeC I added my full log trace and systems.properties file as well